# Popular Methods for Choosing Hyperparameters in Bayesian Statistics

Tags: regression, bayesian, cross-validation, prior, hyperparameter

I'm wondering which methods are commonly used to estimate hyperparameters for priors in Bayesian statistics, and how they work? The setting I'm working with is Bayesian linear regression, so I'm mostly interested in shrinkage priors which have a small number of hyperparameters to tune.

So far I've come across full Bayesian inference, empirical Bayes estimate and cross-validation. However, I've not been able to find good explanations of how full Bayesian inference and the empirical Bayes estimate methods work. I'm familiar with cross-validation for hyperparameter tuning in the machine learning setting, but I'm not sure how it is used for hyperparameter tuning for priors in Bayesian statistics.

Comment: an objective Bayesian would disagree with of estimating priors from the data...

Comment: Possibly you mean that you'd like to estimate hyperparameters for the *posterior* distribution?